# Qt reading from console and stop when Enter has pressed

Tags: c++, qt, text, input, console

```
QTextStream cin(stdin);
QTextStream cout(stdout);

QString path;

cout << "Set directory to save configuration file: ";
cout.flush();
// path = cin.readLine();
cin >> path;
```

Here is the code. It works fine when you need to enter some text into console. It prints message and then waits until you write some text and then press the Enter key. **BUT**, if you don't want to enter any text and you want to leave *path* string empty, this code doesn't approach: it doesn't recognize Enter as end of the line/new line, so if you try to press Enter without writing any text, cursor would be only switched to the next line and program would still wait until you'll write something.

So, is there any way to recognize Enter key **NO MATTER** if *path* string empty or not? Simple: you press Enter key - program stops to read from console.

Comment: Did you try [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) ?

Comment: Or the [`QTextStream` equivalent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine) of `std::getline`?

Comment: Also, please don't name your streams `cin` and `cout`. That will be *very* confusing for readers and maintainers of your code!

Answer (score 2):

The only way i found is to go to the project tab on Qt Creator, got to run, and check run "in terminal" (under "working directory"). This will just run in external terminal which does recognize the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

For QT you could use [`QTextStream::readLine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine).

Instead you could also use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) along with the normal `std::cin` and `std::cout`.